# D register is not updated, why is that?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, nand2tetris

To replicate the `cpu.out` file shown below (though without my comments), 
[use this `cpu.hdl`](https://github.com/havivha/Nand2Tetris/blob/master/05/CPU.hdl), which passes all the tests.

Now, my question is, at clock cycle 3+, 4, and 4+. Notice that `DRegise` (D register) is not updated, despite the command was "D=A-D", why is that?

```
|time| inM  |  instruction   |reset| outM  |writeM |addre| pc  |DRegiste|
a-instruc | store the number "12345"
|0+  |     0|0011000000111001|  0  |      0|   0   |    0|    0|      0 |
|1   |     0|0011000000111001|  0  |      0|   0   |12345|    1|      0 |

c-instru | comp: "A" | dest: "D" | jump: "no jump" | "D=A" 
|1+  |     0|1110110000010000|  0  |  12345|   0   |12345|    1|  12345 |
|2   |     0|1110110000010000|  0  |  12345|   0   |12345|    2|    |

a-instruc | "23456"
|2+  |     0|0101101110100000|  0  |     -1|   0   |12345|    2|  12345 |
|3   |     0|0101101110100000|  0  |     -1|   0   |23456|    3|  12345 |

c-instruc | comp: "A-D" | dest: "D" | jump: "no jump" | "D=A-D"
|3+  |     0|1110000111010000|  0  |  11111|   0   |23456|    3|  11111 |
|4   |     0|1110000111010000|  0  |  12345|   0   |23456|    4|  11111 |

a-instruc | "1000"                        WHY DREGISTE NOT CHANGE? v^v^
|4+  |     0|0000001111101000|  0  | -11111|   0   |23456|    4|  11111 |
|5   |     0|0000001111101000|  0  | -11111|   0   | 1000|    5|  11111 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If your cpu.hdl is passing all the tests, it is probably operating correctly.

As far as I can tell (it's been several years since I built my CPU), the Dreg is being updated correctly; it gets updated in the + cycles. Note that in cycle 3, its value is 12345, and in 3+ (*after* the processing of the D=A-D) it is 11111 (which is 23456-12345, as you would expect).

My best guess is that what is happening is that the simulator doesn't update the values of the outputs of the cpu in the + phases, but does show the internal state. So you see the Dreg change in the + phases, but "addre" (which isn't an internal register, it's the external address lines) only changes in the non-+ phases.